# move cursor and click with Selenium WebDriver ActionChains

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, selenium-webdriver

I have been searching about ActionChain functions to use in BrowserStack.
I would like to remove an app from Facebook. After I worked on it, I recognized that it is not possible to find elements and click and remove the app by normal selenium function such as find_element_by_id and find_element_by_name. So, I decided to use some image processing. I look for the icon of app in page and want to move the cursor on it. After that X button appears. When it appears, I want to click on it. I have found the location of icon and moved the cursor on it by using ActionChain. But, cursor stands on icon for so short time period. And click function of ActionChain does not work. I added my code below. If you can help me about these move cursor and click functions of ActionChain, I would be so happy about that.

libraries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import match_template
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(xa,ya).click().perform()

[the page I am working in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXNxd.png)

code:

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications")
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot('/Users/***/Desktop/ssfordelete.png')
ssfordelete = Image.open("/Users/***/Desktop/ssfordelete.png")
ssfordeleteGray = ssfordelete.convert('L')
ssfordeleteGrayNp = np.asarray(ssfordeleteGray)

allow = Image.open("/Users/***/Desktop/browserStack/allow.png")
allowGray = allow.convert('L')
allowGrayNp = np.asarray(allowGray)
resultdelete1 = match_template(ssfordeleteGrayNp, allowGrayNp)
dij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(resultdelete1), resultdelete1.shape)
sizeofallowx=allowGrayNp.shape[0]
sizeofallowy=allowGrayNp.shape[1]
xa, ya = dij[::-1]
xa = xa + (sizeofallowx/2)
ya = ya + (sizeofallowy/2)
print (xa, ya)
while cntcnt<times:
    temp1 = Image.open("/Users/evrozm/Desktop/browserStack/{}icon.png".format(games[cntcnt]))
    temp1Gray = temp1.convert('L')
    temp1GrayNp = np.asarray(temp1Gray)
    resultdelete1 = match_template(ssfordeleteGrayNp, temp1GrayNp)
    dij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(resultdelete1), resultdelete1.shape)
    sizeoftemp1y=temp1GrayNp.shape[0]
    sizeoftemp1x=temp1GrayNp.shape[1]
    xd1, yd1 = dij[::-1]
    xd1 = xd1 + (sizeoftemp1x/2)
    yd1 = yd1 + (sizeoftemp1y/2)
    print (xd1, yd1)
    ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(xd1,yd1).perform()

    temp2 = Image.open("/Users/evrozm/Desktop/browserStack/delete.png")
    temp2Gray = temp2.convert('L')
    temp2GrayNp = np.asarray(temp2Gray)
    resultdelete2 = match_template(ssfordeleteGrayNp, temp2GrayNp)
    dij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(resultdelete2), resultdelete2.shape)
    xd2, yd2 = dij[::-1]
    sizeoftemp2y=temp1GrayNp.shape[0]
    sizeoftemp2x=temp1GrayNp.shape[1]
    xd2, yd2 = dij[::-1]
    xd2 = xd2 + (sizeoftemp2x/2)
    yd2 = yd2 + (sizeoftemp2y/2)
    print (xd2, yd2)

    ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(xd2,yd2).click().perform()
    cntcnt = cntcnt+1
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not great with Python, but I hope section 7.2 (Action Chains) of the following documentation will help http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Something along these lines possibly: move_to_element_with_offset(to_element, xoffset, yoffset) followed by a click

Comment: I used the information in that link. Instead of moving to element with offset, I directly want to move the cursor to an offset. That why I used move_by_offset. But, I am still thankful for your intention to help.